# Python Group by more than one keys in List of Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, group-by

I have the list of dictionary like:

```
[ {'price': 100,  'product_id': 30089, 'grade_id': 24, 'qty': 1.0},   
  {'price': 200, 'product_id': 30089, 'grade_id': 22, 'qty': 1.0},    
   {'price': 100,  'product_id': 30089, 'grade_id': 24, 'qty': 5.0},   
   {'price': 300, 'product_id': 30993, 'grade_id': 22, 'qty': 1.0} ]
```

Now I want to make group by this List by 2 keys (product_id and grade_id) and the final result will be a new list like:

```
[ {'price': 200,  'product_id': 30089, 'grade_id': 24, 'qty': 6.0},
  {'price': 200, 'product_id': 30089, 'grade_id': 22, 'qty': 1.0}, 
  {'price': 300, 'product_id': 30993, 'grade_id': 22, 'qty': 1.0}]
```

Comment: Please provide any relevant code you have.

Comment: Why is there a qty with 6.0 suddenly?? I am looking at your in- and output and can't figure out what you intend to do.

Comment: The 6.0 comes from 1.0 + 5.0 (similarly the price for that is 200 -> 100 + 100).

Comment: @runDOSrun: I want to do Group by "Product_id" and "grade_id" field.
 As product_id and 'grade_id' fields are same in 1st and 3rd element, it should summed up Qty & Price field values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l=[ {'price': 100,  'product_id': 30089, 'grade_id': 24, 'qty': 1.0},   
   ...:   {'price': 200, 'product_id': 30089, 'grade_id': 22, 'qty': 1.0},    
   ...:    {'price': 100,  'product_id': 30089, 'grade_id': 24, 'qty': 5.0},   
   ...:    {'price': 300, 'product_id': 30993, 'grade_id': 22, 'qty': 1.0} ]

d={}

for x in l:
   ...:     p_id = x['product_id']
   ...:     g_id = x['grade_id']
   ...:     key = str(p_id) + '_' + str(g_id)
   ...:     if not key in d:
   ...:         d[key] = {'price': x['price'] , 'product_id': p_id , 'grade_id': g_id, 'qty': x['qty']}
   ...:     else:
   ...:         d[key]['price'] += x['price']
   ...:         d[key]['qty'] += x['qty']

l1 = [d[x] for x in d]

l1

[{'grade_id': 22, 'price': 200, 'product_id': 30089, 'qty': 1.0},
 {'grade_id': 22, 'price': 300, 'product_id': 30993, 'qty': 1.0},
 {'grade_id': 24, 'price': 200, 'product_id': 30089, 'qty': 6.0}]
```